# Is it possible to move something to address bar from page using animation?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Imagine following problem: on clicking at any image on a specific page I want to change the icon of current extension on the images' thumbnail. To create a thumbnail dynamically is not an issue, it's just that I want to add some animation. Basically, I want the image I've clicked to be transited to the place where current extension icon is drawn, gradually becoming smaller.

So the main question is: is it even possible to implement such kind of animation purely in chrome-extension? In other words, can I position a DOM element (or a just a visual region, whatever) to intersect with address bar.

I guess, I also should know the exact position of current extension icon in toolbar, but this is less important.

So, is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to place arbitrary content over the omnibox.

The closest you can get is the animation of a page action (which resides inside the omnibox). You can pass the data directly from a `<canvas>` element, for an optimal performance. See [`chrome.pageAction.setIcon`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html#method-setIcon).

Note that you can only use a [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html) OR [page action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html), not both, so scrap this solution if you're already using a browser action badge.

---

Yet another solution is to use `history.replaceState` to visually change the URL of the current page (the domain can't be changed, but the path can). This has to be done from a content script. This allows you to "animate" the whole omnibox, by changing characters. I recommend to not use this method though, because it's abuse of the feature.